# Need to fix this prime generating code (SPOJ PRIME1)

Tags: c

I am trying to solve [this](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/PRIME1/) and i came up with this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define primeLimit 100000

int prime (long int Start2,  long int Stop2 )
{
    long int a[primeLimit];
    long int i,j,k,l;
    for (i=Start2;i<=Stop2;i++) {
        a[i] = 1;
    }
    for (i=Start2;i<=Stop2;i++) {
    if (a[i]!= 0 && i!=1) {
        for (j=2; j*j< i;j++) {
            if(i%j==0)
                break;
        }
        if(j*j > i) {
            printf(" \n %d",i);
            l = i;
            for (k = i*i; k< Stop2;) {
                a[k] = 0;
                k = k+l;
            }
        }
        else {
            a[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    long int start,stop,a,look;
    scanf("%ld", &look);
    for (a=1;a<=look;a++) {
        scanf("%ld %ld", &start,&stop);
        prime (start,stop);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am using GNU GCC compiler, CodeBlocks IDE on 32 bit windows 7 PC. The code was fine when i ran it on my compiler. But when submitted it shows runtime error (**SIGSEGV**) .Can anyone point me out where i am going wrong/how to do it better?

Thank you

Comment: It'd be helpful if you included the runtime error in your question

Comment: if Stop2 >= primelimit then you overflow on the initialization of a.

Comment: `long int a[primeLimit];` is going to be extremely cruel to your stack, and just might cause the program to choke. It would be better to allocate the array dynamically, or put it in the data/bss segment (by either placing it at global scope or by making it `static long int a[...];`).

Comment: Why did you leave out the most important info, the inputs? Note Douglas's comment.

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho What are you talking about? `i` ranges from `Start2` to `Stop2`, as it should.

Comment: @JimBalter (s)he doesn't know the inputs, that's part of the point, the program ought to work correctly (and fast) for all inputs within the specified constraints.

Comment: @DanielFischer If the OP doesn't know what inputs caused the SIGSEGV, then s/he should print the inputs. I understand the point, but I'm afraid mine went sailing overhead. There's a good chance that it crashed when the upper limit was >= 100000. The problem description allows up to 1000000000.

Comment: @JimBalter The program is compiled and run on SPOJ's testing machines, you have no way to get the output of your program, so printing the inputs will only result in "Wrong answer" being reported. However, the given constraints are, iirc, that both limits are `<= 10^9`, and the difference between upper and lower limit is `<= 10^5`. So my money is firmly on Douglas nailing the cause.

Comment: @DanielFischer The OP could have tested their program with a range of inputs and seen which ones cause SIGSEGV. While you've expounding on the obvious and missing the point, I've posted an answer. "So my money is firmly on Douglas nailing the cause" -- which I've noted three times now.

Comment: @JimBalter: sorry, I misread the code =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allowed inputs range from 1 to 1000000000, but your array only has 100000 elements .. the difference between the two inputs. You should be indexing it with `i-Start2` or `k-Start2`, not `i` or `k`. And you need `a[primeLimit+1]`, because you need to access  `a[Stop2-Start2]`, i.e., `a[100000]`.

Comment: "You should be indexing it with i-Start2 or k-Start2 ...." I am strugling to visualize this concept. would you please explain with a code snippet. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you can't "visualize" a relative value, I don't think I can help you. The "code snippet" is your own code; use `i-Start2`, not `i`, as the index of `a`, as I said. And why take more than 3 months to read and respond to the answers to your question? What was the point of even asking if you weren't going to read the responses at the time?

Comment: i finally got it .... when you said indexing i was thinking about the loop not the array index itself.... Thanx a lot for your help.... appreciate it... Again sorry for the late response ... i was away from these kind of online judged programming for months

Comment: I wrote "... your array only has .... You should be indexing it ..."; the pronoun "it" refers to "your array".